# Drawbacks of C++20 std::chrono::duration formatting

Tags: c++, formatting, std, c++-chrono, c++20

I needed to print `std::chrono::duration` that may be greater than 24 hours in easily-readable way, like `"2 d. 09:10:11"`.

C++20's `std::chrono::time_point` and `std::chrono::duration` [formatting](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/format) (based on Howard Hinnant's [date library](https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/date.html)) contains tons of useful format specifiers but does not have one for number of days in `std::chrono::duration`. The closest one is `%j` but it pads it with zeros. Also there is no specifier for number of hours within the day. The closest are `%H` (but it includes whole days hours too) and `%OH` (but it crashes on assertion that number of hours is less than 24).

Am I missing something?

Does it make sense to add more specifiers to C++20's `std::format`?

So far I'm using [workaround function](https://godbolt.org/z/QjATZH):

```cpp
#include <chrono>
#include <cstring> // std::strncmp
#include <date.h> // use Howard Hinnant's date library until C++20 is supported by compilers
#include <string>

// Workaround for C++20 std::chrono::format's inability to produce number of days in std::chrono::duration.
// Temporary format specifier for this is `%J`. It must be in the beginning of the format string.
template<typename Rep, typename Period>
std::string duration_to_str(const char* format, const std::chrono::duration<Rep, Period>& duration)
{
    if (std::strncmp(format, "%J", 2))
        return date::format(format, duration);
    static const auto one_day = std::chrono::hours(24);
    const size_t days = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::hours>(duration).count() / 24;
    return std::to_string(days) + date::format(format + 2, duration - days * one_day);
}
```

Test:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

template<typename Rep, typename Period>
void test_dur_to_str(const std::chrono::duration<Rep, Period>& duration)
{
    std::cout << duration_to_str("%T", duration) << ":\n"
              << duration_to_str("%j d. %T", duration) << '\n'
              << duration_to_str("%J d. %T", duration) << "\n\n";
}

int main()
{
    test_dur_to_str(std::chrono::seconds(24 * 60 * 60 - 1));
    test_dur_to_str(std::chrono::seconds(24 * 60 * 60));
    test_dur_to_str(std::chrono::seconds(91297));
    test_dur_to_str(std::chrono::seconds(2 * 24 * 60 * 60 - 1));
    test_dur_to_str(std::chrono::seconds(2 * 24 * 60 * 60));
    test_dur_to_str(std::chrono::seconds(2 * 24 * 60 * 60 + 1));
    test_dur_to_str(std::chrono::seconds(13 * 24 * 60 * 60 + 5));
    test_dur_to_str(std::chrono::seconds(365 * 24 * 60 * 60 + 5));
    test_dur_to_str(std::chrono::seconds(366 * 24 * 60 * 60 + 5));
    test_dur_to_str(std::chrono::seconds(367 * 24 * 60 * 60 + 5));
}
```

Output:

```
23:59:59:
000 d. 23:59:59
0 d. 23:59:59

24:00:00:
001 d. 24:00:00
1 d. 00:00:00

25:21:37:
001 d. 25:21:37
1 d. 01:21:37

47:59:59:
001 d. 47:59:59
1 d. 23:59:59

48:00:00:
002 d. 48:00:00
2 d. 00:00:00

48:00:01:
002 d. 48:00:01
2 d. 00:00:01

312:00:05:
013 d. 312:00:05
13 d. 00:00:05

8760:00:05:
365 d. 8760:00:05
365 d. 00:00:05

8784:00:05:
366 d. 8784:00:05
366 d. 00:00:05

8808:00:05:
367 d. 8808:00:05
367 d. 00:00:05
```

Comment: Do not put answers in your question. If you want to self-answer a question, post it as an answer.

Comment: I've added simplified code based on your and Howard suggestions to my question for two reasons: 1. That code is not an answer to my questions, it's a workaround for the problem I faced. 2. Code in your answer did not compile. Now you fixed it but it gives incorrect results.

Comment: It's OK to post an answer to your own question, and to even accept it. But you have to post it *as an answer*, using the "Add Answer" button at the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I want to show [simplified version](https://godbolt.org/z/eZtvy8) of workaround function, as suggested by Howard Hinnant in his comment, for those who may find it useful:

```cpp
#include <chrono>
#include <cstring> // std::strncmp
#include <date.h> // use Howard Hinnant's date library until C++20 is supported by compilers
#include <string>

template<typename Rep, typename Period>
std::string duration_to_str(const char* format, const std::chrono::duration<Rep, Period>& duration)
{
    if (std::strncmp(format, "%J", 2))
        return date::format(format, duration);
    const auto days = std::chrono::duration_cast<date::days>(duration);
    return std::to_string(days.count()) + date::format(format + 2, duration - days);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just do a `duration_cast` to `std::chrono::days`:

```
template<typename Rep, typename Period>
std::string duration_to_str(const char* format, const std::chrono::duration<Rep, Period>& duration)
{
    if (std::strncmp(format, "%J", 2))
        return date::format(format, duration);

    auto num_days = std::chrono::duration_cast<date::days>(duration);
    return std::to_string(num_days.count()) + date::format(format + 2, duration - num_days);
}
```

As for why it doesn't exist, the purpose of `chrono`'s date/time formatting is for formatting dates and times. Formatting of a date generating a year and a number of days in that year is a date-like operation. Formatting of a date generating a year, month, and number of days in that month is also a date-like operation. The number of days within a duration however isn't really a date-like formatting operation.

It's the same thing as the difference between getting the number of hours within a duration and the 24-hour time that the duration contains. The former is done without consideration of any temporal context; you're just getting the number of hours in a duration. There isn't a formatting field for *that* either.

Comment: There is some sense in what you say but it seems somewhat inconsistent to me. Let's take "17:18:19" as an example, it's 62299 seconds. `%H` is number of full hours. `%M` is number of full minutes in remainder (instead of original time value) after removing number of hours. And so on. Now we have `%j`, which is number of days in a year, but we don't have a way to print remaining part of the time (after reducing by this number of days).
P.S. Thank you for suggestion! `one_day` var is still used (you removed it).

Comment: Not only is a way to do what you want with `days` missing, also missing are other units such as `weeks`, `months`, `years`, `Ks`, `Ms`, and `Gs`.  Ultimately the design is very conservative when it comes to extending the `strftime` formatting flags.  And the workaround is to do exactly what you are doing:  Use chrono to pick apart the units you desire, and then format the extracted numbers from those units as desired.

Comment: If `day_count` is given the type `days` instead of `int`, then the expression `duration - day_count * one_day` simplifies down to just `duration - day_count`.  And then you can send `day_count.count()` to `to_string`.   This also eliminates the need for the `one_day` constant altogether.

Comment: @HowardHinnant, thanks, going to try it right a way. So do you find logic in my arguments for %J?

Comment: @HowardHinnant By the way, I found a typo on your date lib's documentation page and wanted to propose pull request with the fix but then noticed that site's content is newer than corresponding github repo content. So the typo is: replace `%Ex produces the locale's alternate time` with `%EX produces the locale's alternate time` (lowercase x to uppercase X).

Comment: Thanks for the bug report!  I'm very hesitant to further extend the "language" of the formatting flags.  However, there's a process for doing so that _anyone_ can participate in: https://isocpp.org/std/submit-a-proposal .  Perhaps if you bring wider attention to this issue via a proposal, someone might even come up with a more general solution to cover more units than just `days`.

Comment: @4LegsDrivenCat: "*Now we have %j, which is number of days in a year, but we don't have a way to print remaining part of the time (after reducing by this number of days).*" `%j` is the number of days in a year. The remaining part of the time would be the number of *years*. Which you can in fact get... as a year number. We are talking about dates here, after all. The point being that "number of days in the duration" is not really a concept revolving around *dates* or the time of day. It's useful only to a specific epoch, while dates are useful relative to a calendar.

Comment: @NicolBolas "_The remaining part of the time would be the number of years_" Not only the years but the time as well. My point was that `%H%M%S` prints correct values in successively smaller units, whereas I cannot do the same with days. "_We are talking about dates here_" Not only dates but durations as well. If `std::format` is not supposed to be used with durations, it should be disabled at compile time (i.e. accept time_point only).

Comment: @4LegsDrivenCat: "*My point was that %H%M%S prints correct values in successively smaller units, whereas I cannot do the same with days.*" You *can* do that with days. Year, month, day-in-month "%Y%m%d", or year, day-in-year "%Y%j" are both possible. Just like you can get the hours-in-the-day, the minutes-in-the-hour, and the seconds-in-the-minute. But you cannot get more than 24 hours from `%H` even if your duration contains more than 24 hours. Because it doesn't give you the count of hours; it gives you the ***clock time***.

Comment: @NicolBolas You are talking about time_point, I am talking about duration. `std::format` accepts both but it fails to provide ways to print durations longer than 24 hours in easy way, there are just no specifiers for this.

Comment: @4LegsDrivenCat: "*You are talking about time_point, I am talking about duration.*" A time point is just a duration wrapped in an object that knows what clock it came from. How `format` treats the argument is therefore the same either way. It is for formating dates and times; you can't have a time with an hour >= 24, nor can you have a concept of days without a period to limit those days (days in month, days in year, etc). You're asking a screwdriver to work on nails.

Comment: @4LegsDrivenCat: I looked up the various template specializations for formatting in the standard, and it does take durations, but this is [only meant for durations that represent "time since midnight"](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/time.format#4), and if you specify a formatting parameter that doesn't work in that context, you get an exception. This is actually why subtracting the number of days from the duration is important for making the code work.

Comment: @4LegsDrivenCat: Because I realized that your changes were correct. First, despite the fact that you put "C++20" in your question, I realized you weren't talking about the actual C++20 feature but instead the Chrono `date` library, which of course uses a different namespace. Then, once I looked up the documentation about how durations are handled, I could see that a duration longer than 24 hours was not intended to work and thus realized that subtracting the days was a necessary component.

Comment: I refer to C++20 but since none of three compilers I have access to (MSVC, GCC, Clang) supports this part of C++20 yet, I use `date` library.
I don't think that duration longer than 24 hours was not intended to work because I see e.g. `std::chrono::years` in C++20.
So my questions still remain.
I may be wrong but I have a feeling you misunderstood my question. I want `367 d. 00:00:05`, not `8808:00:05` since the former is more readable for a human.